# NextJS dynamic title

Tags: next.js

Have been googling forever and found a way to change the `<title>`. That way is this: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/layout-component

The main problem with this is that everytime someone refresh the site/change page the title goes from `http://localhost:3000` to the actual Title (eg. About us) and I'm a bit afraid of how this is affecting the SEO.

What is the correct way of chaning the page title dynamically?

My layout file:

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import Head from './../node_modules/next/head'

export default function Layout({ children, title = 'Welcome to my website' }) {
  return (
    <div>
        <Head>
          <title>{title}</title>
        </Head>

        {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: import Head doesn't need to be prefixed with ./../node_modules/

Comment: Also, be careful of using this in a layout component, as it may not render on the server side so Google won't pick it up.

Answer (score -14, accepted):

I reninstalled "next" and "next-routes" in my dependencies and now this works.

Comment: wtf.............

Comment: and they ask me why I have trust issues.

Answer (score 16):

Check out [next-seo](https://github.com/garmeeh/next-seo) and install it in your next.js application.

```
yarn add next-seo 
# or 
npm install --save next-seo
```

And it will handle the page title and the meta description for you magically.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { NextSeo } from 'next-seo'; // then add the `NextSeo` at any `pages/` that you wish

export default () => (
  <>
    <NextSeo
      title="About Us, or just any title that you wish"
      description="Then with a short description here."
    />
    <p>Simple Usage</p>
  </>
);
```

I have implemented the same tactic on my own [web app](https://www.lavax.co) here.

Comment: To people who is wandering what that magic is: next-seo adds <Head> component to the page and constructs some tags inside it. Same way as described in @samir answer. Check out this source https://github.com/garmeeh/next-seo/blob/master/src/meta/withHead.tsx

Answer (score 12):

Well for me this works,

Import `<Head>` from next,

```js
import Head from 'next/head'
```

And in return statement,

```js
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
      </Head>
      <section>
          <Your_JSX_CODE>
      </section>
    </>
```

Comment: Yes - note that you can add this to *any* component and it will overwrite the title

Answer (score 5):

If you need a dynamic title/description, for example for the route parameters case, you can do this. (Consider that the page name is [id].js)

```
import React from 'react'
import { NextSeo } from 'next-seo' //as proposed by @xun
// import Head from "next/head" //alternative solution

const Detail = ({id}) => {
  
  const title = `My ${id} title.`
  const description = `My ${id} description.`
  
  return (
     <>
     <NextSeo
      title={title}
      description={description}
    />
    <p>It works!</p>
    </>
    )}

export default Detail
```

And at the end of your file:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({query}) {
  const { id } = query

  return {
    props: {
      id
    },
  };
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: this is the correct answer

Answer (score 5):

## Using the App Router

---

The correct way seems to declare and export `metadata` alongside the `<Page>` component:

```js
    import type { Metadata } from 'next';

    export const metadata: Metadata = {
      title: 'Welcome to my website',
      description: 'Description of my website',
    };

    export default function Page() {
      return '...';
    }
```

At least for static metadata, as per **Dynamic Metadata** there seem to be other methods

More info in the official documentation of [Next.js App Router Seo Metadata](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata#seo)

## Using the Page Router

---

Here documentation suggests to use the `<Head>` component to add elements to the `head` of the page

(As illustrated in [Samir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69625846/16404988))

```js
    import Head from 'next/head';

    function IndexPage() {
      return (
        <div>
          <Head>
            <title>My page title</title>
          </Head>
          <p>Hello world!</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
 
    export default IndexPage;
```

As seen in the official documentation of [Next.js Pages Router "Head" Component](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/head)

---

Although there seems to be some ambiguity between `next/head` "head" and `next/document` "head"

But as user **seho0808** puts it in [this discussion about it](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12290#discussioncomment-809557)  on the official Next.js Github

The supposed uses for them are:

- `next/head` "head" for metadata that can change between pages (e.g. title)
- `next/document` "head" for any "head" code that is common for all pages

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Since Next.js 13, the `<Head>` solution does not work anymore.

Instead `generateMetadata` function should be used :

```
import { Metadata, ResolvingMetadata } from 'next';

type Props = {
  params: { title = 'Welcome to my website', description = 'My Description'  };
};

// set dynamic metadata
export async function generateMetadata({ params }: Props): Promise<Metadata> {
  return {
    title: params.title,
    description: params.description,
  };
}

// page content
export default function Page({ params }: Props) {
  return (
    <></>
  );
}
```

PS: see here for mor details: https://www.slingacademy.com/article/next-js-how-to-set-page-title-and-meta-description/

Answer (score 2):

To achieve head metadata using Next.js 13+ app router, you have two options:

- static metadata
- dynamic metadata.

For **static metadata**, you can export a `metadata` object with the desired metadata fields. For example:

```js
export const metadata = {
   title: "Some static title",
   description: "Some static description"
}
```

This static metadata will be applied to the corresponding page throughout your app.

For **dynamic metadata**, you can export a function called `generateMetadata` that accepts a `params` argument. Inside this function, you can access dynamic parameters defined in your routes. For example, if you have a dynamic parameter called `slug` in a page file `[slug].tsx`, you can fetch data based on the `slug` and return the metadata object. Here's an example:

```js
export async function generateMetadata({ params: { slug } }) {
    const { data: something} = await fetchSomethingBySlug(slug)

    return {
        title: something.title,
        description: something.description,
    }
}
```

This allows you to dynamically generate metadata based on the specific page being rendered.

You can find more information and examples in the Next.js documentation on [generateMetadata](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata).